# Exception setting (example) iBeacon parser layout with Android Beacon Library

Tags: android, ibeacon-android

I have integrated the 2.0-beta6 version of https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library into my Android app. With debug turned on I see my Roximity iBeacons being seen, but being rejected by the beacon parser as the bytes are unexpected.

In the reference application there is the following note:

```
    // By default the AndroidBeaconLibrary will only find AltBeacons.  If you wish to make it
    // find a different type of beacon, you must specify the byte layout for that beacon's
    // advertisement with a line like below.  The example shows how to find a beacon with the
    // same byte layout as AltBeacon but with a beaconTypeCode of 0xaabb
    //
    // beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
    //        setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=aabb,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
    //
    // In order to find out the proper BeaconLayout definition for other kinds of beacons, do
    // a Google search for "setBeaconLayout" (including the quotes in your search.)
```

I created what I thought is the right formatted string (at leas good enough for my test application) and attempted to set it with the following very defensive code:

```
        List<BeaconParser> beaconParsers = beaconManager.getBeaconParsers();
        if (beaconParsers  != null) {
            // We can add a new parser
            String roximityBeaconParser = this.getRoximityBeaconParserString();
            BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser();
            Log.e("iBeacon", "About to set BeaconLayout with " + roximityBeaconParser);
            try {
                beaconParser.setBeaconLayout(roximityBeaconParser);
                beaconParsers.add(beaconParser);
            } catch (BeaconLayoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

My own string caused an error, so I changed my function to get parser string to simply copy the example from the note:

```
private String getRoximityBeaconParserString() {
    String result = "m:2-3:beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25";

    return result;
}
```

The line of code that attempts to set the parser string causes a BeaconLayoutException:

```
beaconParser.setBeaconLayout(roximityBeaconParser);
```

The exception stack trace has no useful information to say what is wrong with the string.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Okay figured it out. I copied the example from the parser function's comment and that has a colon and not an equal character - ironically the parser function's comment is wrong. Thus

```
m:2-3:beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25
```

is wrong, whereas

```
m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25
```

is right. The difference is the "=" character after the "m:2-3" characters.

For reference, the parsing code is found at [The Parsing Source Code](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beacon/BeaconParser.java) has the following patterns:

```
private static final Pattern I_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("i\\:(\\d+)\\-(\\d+)(l?)");
private static final Pattern M_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("m\\:(\\d+)-(\\d+)\\=([0-9A-F-a-f]+)");
private static final Pattern D_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("d\\:(\\d+)\\-(\\d+)([bl]?)");
private static final Pattern P_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("p\\:(\\d+)\\-(\\d+)");
```

This is what the string is parsed against.

What is not clear from the documentation is that the parsing function requires a (single) power ("p") element, requires a (single) matching ("m") element, and at least one identifier ("i") element to be valid. Otherwise an exception is thrown.

As we can't see/debug into the parser method, I ended up copying the top level method into my class (along with the initialized variables it relies on) and then called the local copy of the function to figure out why it was complaining. The big issue is that if there is a term (one of the comma separated values) that does not perfectly match against the patterns then a general purpose "can't parse this term" exception is thrown and that is not easy to debug. Hence I copied the function and called it to see what was thrown and why.

Comment: Thanks for troubleshooting this, and sorry for the trouble.  Mind opening an issue in GitHub against the open source library?

Comment: @davidgyoung Sure - I'll try to get that done this weekend. If I don't then nag me, in case I forget. There is also a mistake in an exception message (copy/paste error) raised with a missing term - there are two "you need an m term" messages. I'll put all of this together in my defect report. Great library, currently focused on why I'm not getting a notification now the parser recognizes my iBeacon. Knowing where the source code is on github makes this oh so much easier.